# apache virtual host problem on windows 7 - please explain

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, lamp, windows-7, localhost

This problem has never occurred in the past (i have tried this many times) but this time,

ALL virtual hosts defined in the virtual-hosts.conf file in the apache installation directory direct the browser to the apache server documentRoot directory.

I am using windows 7 with the latest version of apache.

These are the virtual hosts defined

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.a.local
    ServerAlias dev.a.local
    DocumentRoot "D:/wwwroot/a/public"
    ErrorLog "logs/a.log"
    CustomLog "logs/a-access.log" common

    <Directory "D:/wwwroot/a/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
     Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.b.local
    ServerAlias dev.b.local
    DocumentRoot "D:/wwwroot/b/public"
    ErrorLog "logs/b.log"
    CustomLog "logs/b-access.log" common

    <Directory "D:/wwwroot/b/public"s>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
     Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have modified the hosts file and added

```
127.0.0.1 dev.a.local 
127.0.0.1 dev.b.local
```

When i try to access dev.a.local or dev.b.local i am directed to the documentRoot of apache defined in httpd.conf.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be all there is to it, but at the **VERY** beginning of that config file, put this line:

```
Listen 80
```

This tells Apache to actually listen for requests on port 80, and should help it work with the `NameVirtualHost` directive.

ALSO!!!
You have a typo on line 33:

```
<Directory "D:/wwwroot/b/public"s>
```

Should the problem persist, post your entire config file and I'll be happy to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Directives are taken from a separate conf file. The Listen directive exists in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Ok, just checking. Non-standard (Linux) installations of Apache always differ day to day, from past experience. Best of luck. Was your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the virtual hosts configuration file is not commented out in httpd.conf (as it is by default).

**Example** (Mac paths)

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

to

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```